# From a TSP to a Minimal Euclidean Matching by Removing Edges

Tags: probability, combinatorics, optimization, point-processes

Both the **[optimal tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)** though 30 Euclidean points and a **[perfect matching](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html)** constructed by removing every other edge, are displayed below:

[image]

Is the matching minimal? If not, why not?

What operation is performed to the matching to shorten it, assuming this is possible? I understand one must construct an augmenting path though the points which misses some of the matching's edges, but why is such a path likely to exist? Or is it unlikely to exist?

Comment: Do you mean *minimum* instead of *minimal*?

Comment: I understand that, for example at the far top right of the graphics, "switching" the two edges will shorten the matching. Is there more mathematical depth, or is that it?

Comment: Clement, yes. I mean the sum of the edges is as small as possible.